# Converting a timer to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Still learning react and there's several instances of which I'm trying to understand states & props. Was hoping someone can show me how I'd convert something like below.

```js
    const display = document.querySelector('#time');
    const countdown = new CountDownTimer(120);
    const timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(120);

    format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

    countdown.onTick(format);

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        countdown.start();
    });

    function format(minutes, seconds) {
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
        display.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/robbmj/simple-js-countdown-timer/master/countdowntimer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <button>Start Count Down</button>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would suggest dropping the countdowntimer.js and just build your React project from scratch.  You should be able to do this with a single React component.  Posting your attempt will likely get you more help where you need it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is make a react class that is your timer.

this is a rough overview you will probably have to play with the data a little.. but should get you started. Note, it accepts milliseconds and converts to seconds and minutes

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ms: props.ms
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval( () => {
            if ((this.state.ms) <= 0) {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
                this.forceUpdate();
                return;
            }
            this.setState({ms: this.state.ms - 1000});
        }, 1000)
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
    format() {
        const { ms } = this.state;
        let seconds = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
        let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

        minutes = minutes < 1 ? '00' : minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 1 ? '00' : seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
        return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.format(this.state.ms)}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

The way you would use it is something like...

```
<Timer ms={15000} />
```

Comment: Thanks. I see what you did there with the props to pass it. Definitely need to tweak the digits but it's a great start for me.

Comment: I've fixed the data via mod `seconds = seconds % 60;seconds = seconds < 10 ? \`0${seconds}\` : seconds;`. 

Is there a way to include or start `<Timer ms={15000} />` in a component via an action? My specific need is I am opening this in a modal so I only want this timer to start when modal opens and clear once closed.

Comment: @DaveBergschneider you are describing conditionally rendering something. There are a lot of examples of how to do that, i'd recommend you do a little research. But the idea is on button click you set a state that shows the modal. when you go to show the modal you can conditionally render children in it via the same way you show the modal. `{this.state.someFlagToShowModal ? <Timer ms={somthing} /> : null }`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have the modal working via states. This gives me a good idea. I'm finding react to be simpler than I thought but managing states and passing props to be counter intuitive or at least not productive yet.

Comment: @DaveBergschneider Yea it takes a little bit to get the hang of it.. when you do though its an amazingly powerful tool! Let me know if you're unable to get the hang of it still and if so I'll help out more :)